# Build rpms with llvm

Tags: llvm, fedora, rpm, rpmbuild, chroot

I have some source rpms (lets say rsync-3.1.1-7.fc23.src.rpm) and I want to build it with llvm instead of gcc. What is the most convenient way of doing this?

My setup is a Fedora 23 VM and I would prefer if I don't have to setup something really complicated. Is there a way somehow to just do an rpmbuild under chroot maybe, somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this, and it *looks* like it worked...

```
export CC=clang
export CXX=clang++
rpmbuild --rebuild rsync-3.1.1-7.fc23.src.rpm
```

I tested it by first putting bogus values for `CC` and `CXX`, and the `configure` script failed.